# PHP encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
$a=file_get_contents("http://www.ciao.de/Erfahrungsberichte/8x4_Wild_Flower_Deo_Spray__8937431");
preg_match('/dass auf dem Versch(.*)ziehen mich/Us',$a,$b);
$b=$b[1];
echo $b."\n";
echo utf8_encode($b)."\n";
echo mb_convert_encoding($b,'UTF-8','iso-8859-1')."\n";
```

results in

```
lussdeckel riesengro▒ und un▒bersehbar glitzernd ein ▒New▒ prangt. Neue Produkte
lussdeckel riesengroß und unübersehbar glitzernd ein �New� prangt. Neue Produkte
lussdeckel riesengroß und unübersehbar glitzernd ein �New� prangt. Neue Produkte
```

HTTP source code suggests in meta tag to use "iso-8859-1". German umlauts are fine, but why are the quotes around "New" not converted correctly? In PHP **[manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php#93162)**  there is a function fix_latin. When using this function the quotes are also converted correctly!?

PS: same occurs with european currency symbol € (EUR) - it's also converted wrong (except with the fix_latin function), but why?

Comment: Try setting the character-encoding in the HTTP meta to be utf8, and see if that works.

Comment: Hum, I don't own ciao.de so I cannot influence it. I'd like to crawl some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euro sign is not in ISO-8859-1. (ISO-8859-15 was created for that purpose.)

Best I recollect, `mb_convert_encoding()` will not transliterate characters. Consider using [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) instead. And/or be sure to set the `content-type` header as needed.

In the next PHP version there will also be the [Transliterator class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php), which wraps ICU.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($b,'UTF-8','ISO-8859-15')` doesn't work, `iconv('ISO-8859-15','UTF-8',$b)` doesn't work too. I think, I'm going to use fix_latin function in case of ISO-8859-1* encoding and `mb_convert_encoding()` else.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Also, keep in mind that if your string is `ISO-8859-15` already (which is possible, if it's user-input), telling PHP to read it as `UTF-8` and convert it to `ISO-8859-15` may indeed result in garbage. :-)

Comment: That's clear. I'm not telling PHP to read it as UTF-8. For that, I'm parsing HTTP response header and HTTP content and looking for a `Content-Type` declaration. When I found such a tag then I'll call `mb_convert_encoding` to convert this encoded content to UTF-8.

Comment: This extension (INTL, therefore transliterate) is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0. Alternatively, the PECL version of this extension may be used with all PHP versions greater than 5.2.0 (5.2.4+ recommended).

Comment: @user672452: That does only work if the encoding had been properly named in the original file / headers.